# Can we iterate over all EventEmitter decorated with @Output() in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript1.8, reflect-metadata

What I want to achieve is for a given component instance I want to iterate over all the `EventEmitter` decorated with `@Output`.

For e.g.

**my-component**

```
   @Component({
     moduleId: module.id,
     selector: "my-component",
     template: "<h1>My Component!!"
   })
   export class MyComponent{ 
     @Output() emitter1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
     @Output() emitter2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
   }
```

so lets say I am loading this component dynamically like below,

```
   this._cr.resolveComponent(MyComponent).then(cmpFactory => {
        this.testComponentContainer.clear();
        let instance: any = this.testComponentContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory).instance;

        // Here I want to iterate over EventEmitter dynamically
        // So that I may bind to both emitter1 and emitter2
    });
```

Can i do this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the `propMetadata` metadata to find out the decorated output.

Here is a sample:

```
this._cr.resolveComponent(MyComponent).then(cmpFactory => {
    this.testComponentContainer.clear();
    let instance: any = this.testComponentContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory).instance;

    var propMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', MyComponent);
    var outputs = propMetadata.filter(metadata => {
      return (metadata instanceof OutputMetadata);
    });

    outputs.forEach(output => {
      output.subscribe(event => {
        // handle event
      });
    });

    // Here I want to iterate over EventEmitter dynamically
    // So that I may bind to both emitter1 and emitter2
});
```

**Update by Madhu Ranjan**
There are issues with above code, However it hinted me to use it correctly like below,

```
   this._cr.resolveComponent(componentToTest).then(cmpFactory => {
        this.testComponentContainer.clear();
        let instance: any =   this.testComponentContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory).instance;

        let propMetadata: any = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', componentToTest);
        let outputs: any = [];

        for (let key in propMetadata) {
            if (propMetadata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (propMetadata[key].length > 0) {
                    let _hasOutput = propMetadata[key].filter(metadata => {
                        return (metadata instanceof OutputMetadata);
                    });

                    if (_hasOutput && _hasOutput.length > 0) {
                        outputs.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        outputs.forEach(output => {
            instance[output].subscribe(event => {
                // Logic to use event data..
            });
        });
    });
```